# Joins and looking for NULL values

Tags: 7, database

I'm using the flag module to let users mark their questions as solved, similar to how it works on this site. I therefore want to let users filter posts to show only unsolved questions. Additionally, some posts might not be questions at all. Therefore, they can't have a "solved" flag, but they also should NOT appear in the results when filtering only by unsolved questions. Therefore, I need to join the node table with two others: `flag_content` and `field_data_field_question` (this latter table is what tells whether or not a post is a question).

Here's the current code I'm trying:

```
$query->join('flag_content', 'f', 'f.content_id = n.nid AND f.content_type = "node" AND f.fid = 5');
$query->join('field_data_field_question', 'q', 'q.entity_id = n.nid AND q.field_question_value = 1');
$query->condition('f.fid', 'NULL', 'IS');
$query->condition('q.field_question_value', 'NULL', 'IS NOT');
```

However, this results in the following error:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''NULL') AND (q.field_question_value IS NOT 'NULL')
LIMIT 21 OFFSET 0' at line 4: SELECT n.nid AS nid
FROM
{node} n
INNER JOIN {field_data_field_category} t ON t.entity_id = n.nid
INNER JOIN {flag_content} f ON f.content_id = n.nid AND f.content_type = "node" AND f.fid = 5 
INNER JOIN {field_data_field_question} q ON q.entity_id = n.nid AND q.field_question_value = 1
WHERE (t.field_category_tid = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (f.fid IS :db_condition_placeholder_1) AND (q.field_question_value IS NOT :db_condition_placeholder_2)
LIMIT 21 OFFSET 0; Array 
( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 464 [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => NULL [:db_condition_placeholder_2] => NULL
)
in queryExecuteRender_recentActivity() (line 57 of someFile.php).
```

Is this not the correct way to pass `NULL` values into a query?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The database API actually has a preferred way to add expressions of this type, namely the [`SelectQuery::isNull()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3AisNull/7) and [`SelectQuery::isNotNull()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3AisNotNull/7) functions. You can use them like this:

```
$query->isNull('f.fid');

$query->isNotNull('q.field_question_value');
```